# Как сделать чтобы стиль использовал данные из своего контрола?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать чтобы стиль использовал данные из своего контрола?

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ColumnWidth="100">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding //тут нужно привязаться к ToolTipText}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <local:DataGridTextColumnWithHeader   
                                    Header="!hello"
                                    ToolTipText="hello!"
                                    />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Реализация `DataGridTextColumnWithHeader`:

```
 public class DataGridTextColumnWithHeader : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ToolTipTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolTipTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipText", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridTextColumnWithHeader));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, это на самом деле не так просто, поскольку `Column`-объекты `DataGrid` не являются частью визуального дерева, и до них так просто не достучаться.

Но в вашем случае можно дать колонке имя, и достучаться по имени:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="100">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding ToolTipText, ElementName=ColumnWithHeader}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:DataGridTextColumnWithHeader x:Name="ColumnWithHeader"
                            Header="!hello"
                            ToolTipText="hello!"
                            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

Если вы не хотите делать по стилю для каждой колонки, можно обойтись без этого, используя code behind:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="100" Loaded="OnDGLoaded" Name="DG">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:DataGridTextColumnWithHeader Header="!hello" ToolTipText="hello!"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
void OnDGLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var header in GetVisualChildrenOfType<DataGridColumnHeader>(DG))
    {
        DataGridTextColumnWithHeader column = header.Column as DataGridTextColumnWithHeader;
        if (column != null)
            header.ToolTip = column.ToolTipText;
    }
}

IEnumerable<T> GetVisualChildrenOfType<T>(FrameworkElement fe) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    T t = fe as T;
    if (t != null)
        yield return t;
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(fe);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(fe, i) as FrameworkElement;
        if (child != null)
        {
            foreach (var r in GetVisualChildrenOfType<T>(child))
                yield return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Это присвоит тултип только один раз, при загрузке. Если этого недостаточно, можно установить привязку вручную, благо оба объекта у вас в цикле `OnDGLoaded` есть.

Comment: Сорри, немного неправильно задал вопрос, но уже отредактировал.

Comment: @Lightness: Готово, проверяйте.

Comment: А без имени никак нельзя? Планируется создавать множество `Column`-обьектов, а стиль для них сделать один. Или придется создавать на каждый `Column` свой стиль и обращаться напрямую к имени?

Comment: @Lightness: Я пока не нашёл другого решения. Проблема в том, что у `DataGridColumnHeader`'а нет доступа к `Column`. Т. к. Column вообще можно быть не в визуальном дереве. Но возможно, по идее, решение с code behind.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста! Я ещё подумаю над решением через XAML.

Comment: @Lightness: Обновил ответ, добавил решение с code behind и без стиля.

Comment: Попробую применить в проекте. Спасибо :)

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!